# setting custom format in vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, format

I have a 9 digit number that i'm storing in my SQL SERVER DB. What I'm trying to do is enter it on a report in a particular format. The number might looks like this...

```
012345678
```

And I'm trying to display it in this format?

```
012-34-5678W
```

Is this doable to set in the the formats - or would I have to Select it in this format in my SQL SERVER query?

EDIT: this is how it's selected and loaded. Not sure if I should format is somehow before it gets loaded. Value3 is my value that i'm trying to format!

```
sql="Select Value1, Value2, Value3 from tblA"

cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, conn)
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

dt.Load(reader)
Return dt
```

Currently I have a function in place that basically changes the formatting of the number to display it in the correct format in a field that I show in the app. I'm hoping to basically take the value and call the function to update it before i do...

```
dt.load(reader)
```

However I'm not sure how I'd specify that I want that specific column to be updated? Also they might be multiple records

Or would I have to do it after I load it?

Comment: In that format, it is no longer a number but text.  Especially with the trailing character

Comment: @plutonix - am i not able to able to format it? the thing is I'm selecting it directly with SQL and loading it to datatable - so I'm not sure if something like that needs to be formatted before it gets loaded into DT

Comment: Is it really stored as a number?  Leading zeds are not typically stored/shown *on numbers*

Comment: @plutonix - varchar ....sorry

Comment: It would be better if it was stored as a number. Then when you want to display it in a report, you could use the custom format string "000-00-0000W" to format it the way you want.

Comment: the thing I just realized is that this number might occasionally get stored with letters - such as AAA000000 - so it owuld need to be formatted to AAA-00-0000W @Blackwood

Comment: I don't think your report will have custom formatting for strings (they are generally assumed to be already formatted the way you want). If you are storing it as a string in your database, perhaps you should store it already formatted the way you want.

Comment: @blackwood that would make sense but theres already thousands of records stored like that. To display it properly in a text box we have a function that goes by position (mid) and sets it in the proper format. Im trying to include it in that same format in rdlc report

Comment: @plutonix - would you be able to take a look at my edit please.

Comment: Where does the `W` come from?  Is it fixed or is it the first letter of some other field? I am a little unclear on what you are asking - are you looking for a column property to format this for you sort of like access, or just how to format a string?

Comment: No, W is fixed and will always be the last digit/letter at the end of the number. I basically want to select all my data as i show in the EDIT, and then grab all the values from a column called "Value3" and then re-format all the rows with my hand written function (which adds hyphens and "W") and gets updated in the DT so that it looks like I need it to. I already use this function to reformat it when I display it in the application. This way when I link my dataset with datatable to report the value will look proper.